# Hibernate Criteria - org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteria, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to use criteria for select the values from many-to-one releationship mapped field.But i'm getting error`org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:part_id of:`. Please see my pojo classes and advise what is the wrong here.

```
Criteria partCriteria = session.createCriteria(PartFeatureVersion.class);
partCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("part_id",part.getPart_id()));


@Entity
@Table(name="DBO.PART_FEATURE_VERSION")
public class PartFeatureVersion {
private Part part;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="part_id")
    public Part getPart() {
        return part;
    }


@Entity
@Table(name="DBO.PART")
public class Part {

private String part_id;
    private Set<PartFeatureVersion> partfeatureversion = new HashSet<PartFeatureVersion>(0);

    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="PART_ID")
public String getPart_id() {
    return part_id;
}

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="part")
public Set<PartFeatureVersion> getPartfeatureversion() {
    return partfeatureversion;
}
```

if create getters/setters in PartFeatureVersion pojo class , its giving error as `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:PART_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Hibernate, but is it able to perform this mapping without setters for the mapped fields?

Comment: I am also not sure but it looks there is `part_id` should be in CAPS for `@JoinColumn(name="part_id")`

Comment: Make sure the name of columns match exactly as they are named in db.

Comment: I have tried part_id as caps in @JoinColumn(name="PART_ID", itdidn't work well.As well all db names are match with pojo classes.

Comment: Here getters and setters are not created in the pojo class, if i creating pojo then its error "org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:"

Comment: `part_id` is not part of your class `PartFeatureVersion`. It is in is another class `Part`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the following code:

```
partCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("part_id",part.getPart_id()));
```

into:

```
partCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("part", part));
```

The criteria in your code is based on `PartFeatureVersion` class. You are restricting the criteria based on `PartFeatureVersion.part_id` property.  The problem is your `PartFeatureVersion` class doesn't have a property called `part_id`.

Comment: I have changed the code , but now i'm getting error as `org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of Part.part_id`.

Comment: Do you forget to replace `part.getPart_id()` into `part`?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me.

I fixed it by matching the sintax's upper and lower case description field when used in the criteria, and match the fielname declared in the DTO class.